# "Snakemake" call mpirun using multiple nodes and a slurm-clusterprofile

Tags: cluster-computing, profile, slurm, snakemake, openmpi

I am writing a snakemake-workflow which calls a process using mpirun in a slurm-job using a docker-image. It is necessary to use multiple computing nodes and lots of processes. I am using a slurm-cookiecutter-template for the slurm-profile.

Currently I am calling mpirun with the -oversubscribe- Option. I dont think it is supposed to be like this. Also, I cant figure out how to call the right resources in multi-node-jobs

As an example, the rule defines "threads: 10". In the slurm-profile I am defining "nodes:2" , "ntasks_per_node = 1" and "cpus_per_task=5". Somehow this gives me 20 cpu's using 10 cpus per node.

I am new to the snakemake-craft and I guess I did not fully explain my issue here. If you need more information, please ask!

Thanks in advance.

Content of config.yaml from the clusterprofile

```
restart-times: 0
jobscript: "slurm-jobscript.sh"
cluster: "slurm-submit.py"
cluster-status: "slurm-status.py"
max-jobs-per-second: 1
max-status-checks-per-second: 10
local-cores: 1
latency-wait: 60
use-singularity: True
rerun-incomplete: True

# Example resource configuration
default-resources:
  - runtime=100
  - mem_mb=12000
  - disk_mb=1000000
  - nodes=1
#  - ntasks_per_node=1
# # set-threads: map rule names to threads
set-threads:
   - execute=10
# # set-resources: map rule names to resources in general
set-resources:
   - execute:nodes=2
```

Container environment / params.environment:

```
env: "set +euo pipefail;.  /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2006/etc/bashrc ;set -euo pipefail;"
```

PART of the rule "execute":

-changes directory into the simulation-directory

-sources openfoam-environment (unfortunately needs +euo to be set)

-calls mpirun

```
    resources:
        attempt=3,
        mem_mb=32000
    container:
        "docker://openfoamplus/of_v2006_centos73"
    log: f"logs/{paramspace.wildcard_pattern}/execute.log"
    shell:
        """
        (
        cd {params.casedirs}
        {params.environment}
        mpirun --oversubscribe -np {threads} rhoPimpleFoam -parallel
        ) >> {log}
        """
```

My questions:

1. Do I make use of my resources correctly? When I define the run with 2 nodes and 10 threads I would get 20 cpu's?
2. Why do I need to call mpirun with "--oversubscribe"? I don't really want that

Comment: Can you provide your `cluster` option as well?  That's how snakemake translates the resources and profile to an sbatch command.  Are you using the slurm cookie cutter profile?

Comment: I added the configuration file "config.yaml" from the profile and the rule (without input / output-definition)

Comment: I did not answer your latter question yet :  yes, I am using the slurm -  cookiecutter - template

Comment: Based on what you posted and the slurm profile, threads was set to 10 and is used for `cpus-per-task`, so with 2 nodes you get 20 cores in the sbatch command.  What are you trying to do that isn't working?  Is there a particular sbatch configuration you are trying to replicate?

Comment: I guess I did not formulate my question well. Thats because I am not really aware of the things I am doing here.

1. I don't want to use the --oversubscribe option of mpirun. I am not totally sure weather I am using my resources right
2. I want to scale my resources and I don't know how snakemake is working here. When I have 2 nodes and 5 tasks I get 10 cpus, right? How can I be sure that when I call mpirun with "-np 10" that all cpu's are used? I am not sure if I just use 5 cpu's with 2 tasks/cpu.